# TNS BUILD FAILED: Error- cannot access IdentityCredential (NativeScript)

Tags: sdk, nativescript, nativescript-angular, tns, angular-nativescript

Installed nativescript, cloned the repo, while building the app for android using "tns build android"
Facing this error:

[Exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Da1S.png)

Tried specifying the compileSdkVersion 30 as well in the app.gradle file.